# Is SQL Server Analysis Services suitable for near-realtime KPI calculation?

Tags: ssas, olap, kpi

I design a system that should calculate several KPI indicators. There is a relatively simple transactional database, data from this database are transferred to SQL Server data warehouse (1 facts table, 5 dimension tables). Fact table contains data about call-center phone sessions.
Near 1000 new fact table rows per second are being added to the data warehouse.

I need to build KPI indicators (e.g. average call length per call-center operator for last 2 hours). And the time from data update (new fact row) till KPI update should be less than 2 seconds.

Is it possible to build such fast solution using SQL Server Analysis Services?

Comment: In case SSAS is not suitable or you're not limited to SSAS, you might have a look to icCube; the upcoming v3 is supporting incremental update (real-time) of the cube.

Comment: All other parts of solution (OLAP for daily reports) are built using SQL Server. So for these fast indicators I choose between SSAS and custom solution.